# Load table from Oracle to MYSQL using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, oracle, mysql-python

Tried below code to load rows from Source(Oracle) to Target(MYSQL)

```
for row in source_cursor:
        target_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO JOB (SUBJECT_AREA,WORKFLOW_NAME,VERSION_NUMBER,SUBJECT_ID,WORKFLOW_ID,WORKFLOW_RUN_ID,WORKLET_RUN_ID,CHILD_RUN_ID,INSTANCE_ID,INSTANCE_NAME,TASK_ID,TASK_TYPE_NAME,TASK_TYPE,START_TIME,END_TIME,RUN_ERR_CODE,RUN_ERR_MSG,RUN_STATUS_CODE,TASK_NAME,TASK_VERSION_DECIMAL,SERVER_ID,SERVER_NAME)   VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15,:16,:17,:18,:19,:20,:21,:22)",(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20],row[21]))
```

**Error**

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

**Edited**
**Updated Code_:-**

```
SQL="SELECT SUBJECT_AREA, WORKFLOW_NAME, VERSION_NUMBER, SUBJECT_ID, WORKFLOW_ID, WORKFLOW_RUN_ID, WORKLET_RUN_ID, CHILD_RUN_ID, INSTANCE_ID, INSTANCE_NAME,TASK_ID, TASK_TYPE_NAME, TASK_TYPE, TO_CHAR(START_TIME, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_CHAR(END_TIME, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), RUN_ERR_CODE, RUN_ERR_MSG, RUN_STATUS_CODE, TASK_NAME, TASK_VERSION_NUMBER, SERVER_ID, SERVER_NAME FROM JOB WHERE TRUNC(END_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) or END_TIME IS NULL"

source_cursor = connection.cursor()
source_query=source_cursor.execute(SQL)

target_cursor = myDB.cursor()
sql = """INSERT INTO JOB_target (SUBJECT_AREA, WORKFLOW_NAME, VERSION_NUMBER,SUBJECT_ID, WORKFLOW_ID, WORKFLOW_RUN_ID, WORKLET_RUN_ID,CHILD_RUN_ID, INSTANCE_ID, INSTANCE_NAME, TASK_ID, TASK_TYPE_NAME, TASK_TYPE, START_TIME, END_TIME, RUN_ERR_CODE,RUN_ERR_MSG, RUN_STATUS_CODE, TASK_NAME, TASK_VERSION_DECIMAL,SERVER_ID, SERVER_NAME)  VALUES({prms})""".format(prms=", ".join(['%s'] * 22))
target_cursor.executemany(sql, [row for row in source_cursor])
source_cursor.close()
target_cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

**Error:**

```
mysql_connection_v2.py:40: Warning: Data truncated for column 'START_TIME' at row 1
  target_cursor.executemany(sql, [row for row in source_cursor])
mysql_connection_v2.py:40: Warning: Data truncated for column 'START_TIME' at row 2
  target_cursor.executemany(sql, [row for row in source_cursor])
mysql_connection_v2.py:40: Warning: Data truncated for column 'START_TIME' at row 3
  target_cursor.executemany(sql, [row for row in source_cursor])
mysql_connection_v2.py:40: Warning: Data truncated for column 'START_TIME' at row 4
```

Comment: Please show definition of `source_cursor()`. Does it run after `execute` or `fetchall`?

Comment: Parfait, I have edit the code to give more clear picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, while all strive to adhere to [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), no two DB-APIs are exactly the same especially in parameter implementation. Specifically, while the module, [`cxOracle`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html), supports arbitrary placeholders like numbered sequence `:1`, `:2`, `:3`, etc. the module [`MySQLdb`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) only supports `%s` or`%(name)s` parameter style.

Therefore, adjust prepared SQL statement accordingly. Additionally, consider `format` to dynamically write placeholders via a list (`["%s", "%s", %s", ...]`) to avoid long unnumbered write-out and [`executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) to avoid looping.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO JOB (SUBJECT_AREA, WORKFLOW_NAME, VERSION_NUMBER, 
                          SUBJECT_ID, WORKFLOW_ID, WORKFLOW_RUN_ID, WORKLET_RUN_ID, 
                          CHILD_RUN_ID, INSTANCE_ID, INSTANCE_NAME, TASK_ID, 
                          TASK_TYPE_NAME, TASK_TYPE, START_TIME, END_TIME, RUN_ERR_CODE,
                          RUN_ERR_MSG, RUN_STATUS_CODE, TASK_NAME, TASK_VERSION_DECIMAL, 
                          SERVER_ID, SERVER_NAME)   
         VALUES({prms})
      """.format(prms=", ".join(['%s'] * 22))

target_curosr.excecutemany(sql, tuple(source_cursor))
connection.commit()
```

But if you were using a loop, simply pass the row *itself* and not unpack each of its elements or use indexing to needed point:

```
for row in source_cursor:
     target_cursor.execute(sql, row)

for row in source_cursor:
     target_cursor.execute(sql, row[:21])
```

Comment: To this, I would add the tip that when fetching the data from Oracle DB, make sure to tune [Cursor.arraysize](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html?highlight=arraysize#Cursor.arraysize) since you are likely fetching multiple rows.  See [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#tuning-fetch-performance).

Comment: Parfait, I  have edit the description. I am getting above error warning.

Comment: That is not an error but a warning where data is truncated in MySQL at that column. Consider modifying Oracle query on `START_TIME` to align to MySQL? Maybe you are using `date` instead of `datetime`? Also, do you see data appended in MySQL? Be sure to `commit` changes. Also, you may be able to just pass in `tuple(source_cursor)` instead of the list comprehension.

Comment: Correct, Datatype was different in MYSQL. THanks a lot, Parfait(Perfect) :)